# Can I somehow monitor which files/folders are added by an installer?

Tags: macos, install

I'm wondering where the installer for Dell printer drivers puts its files. I didn't find any in "All My Files", also the contents of my Application/Dell folder stayed unchanged.

Is there a way to monitor the installation process more closely so as to able to follow which files are created/destroyed and where ?

Comment: Drivers are installed in locations which do not show up in "All My Files". If you are trying to solve printer problems, a question focusing on that might yield better results.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to view what an *installer* does, but you can watch the install script using [lsof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317177/see-what-process-is-using-a-file-in-mac-os-x) to try to figure out what files it opens.